# How can limit number of page and drag to last record with viewpager?

Tags: android

Suppose I have 1000 records in database and I want to load them on viewpager. I also want my viewpager will be limited just in 20 pages. As you see,it can't be drag anymore if viewpager reach to last position(20). How can I drag more if the last position it is not the last record yet?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ViewPagerHelper mViewPagerHelper = ViewPagerHelper.getInstance();
        mViewPagerHelper.dateBarFunction(this);

    }

}
```

ViewPagerHelper class

```
public class ViewPagerHelper {
    private static ViewPagerHelper sViewPagerHelper = null;
    private String[] mNumberList= new String[1001];
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    public ViewPagerHelper() {
    }

    public static ViewPagerHelper getInstance() {
        if (sViewPagerHelper == null) {
            sViewPagerHelper = new ViewPagerHelper();
        }
        return sViewPagerHelper;
    }

    public void dateBarFunction(Activity activity){
        mViewPager= (ViewPager) activity.findViewById(R.id.date_area);
        mViewPager.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        final ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(activity, getNumberList());
        mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(20);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);


        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
    }


    private String[] getNumberList() {
        Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {
            mNumberList[i] = ""+i;
        }

        return mNumberList;

    }


}
```

ViewPagerAdapter class

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    String[] mNumberList;


    public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, String[] mNumberList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mNumberList= mNumberList;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup container, final int position) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_adapter, container, false);


        TextView dateArea = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dateArea);
        dateArea.setText(mNumberList[position]);


        ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);
        return itemView;

    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        // Remove viewpager_item.xml from ViewPager
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 20;
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "drag more" ? Why should the pager move any further when the last position is reached?

Comment: No,please read carefully again. I want to limit in 20 pages, but I have 1000 records. On the example above,I set last position at 19, there are 981 records more.

Comment: did you have a look at this blog - http://thehayro.blogspot.in/2012/12/enable-infinite-paging-with-android.html?

Comment: No,I did not.Thank you for your help ;)